# What is the length of the sides of a hexagon containing 19 x Ø2" billiard balls?

Tags: circles

I'm looking to make a hexagon wooden rack to hold 19 x Ø2" billiard balls. What is the length of the inside sides of the hexagon containing 19 x Ø2" billiard balls?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?

Comment: I have, but as the inside corners of the hexagon extend beyond the edge of the balls I'm struggling to get an exact measurement, and the rack needs to be fairly precise to hold the balls. I was hoping there was a simple mathematical equation to determine the size of the hexagon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]  
[image]

As $AB=OB\tan(30^\circ)=1''\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$ and $BD=OO_1=2''$ then the side length will be $\dfrac{2(\sqrt{3}+6)}{3}\approx 5.1574 ('')$.